# boost.log std::exception formatter unable to find operator<< overload in own namespace

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading, boost-log

I have created a simple formatter for boost.log like shown in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html) example for `std::exception`. Now if i want to use the overloaded operator, which is defined in my own namespace, log is unable to find the overload.

Some code:

```
namespace my_space {
template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT >
std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& operator<< (std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& strm, std::exception const& e) {
    // some printout stuff here
    strm << e.what();
    return strm;
}
} // namespace my_space
```

But if i move (Stroustrup please don't shot me, it was only for testing) the overload into std namespace it will be found by the formatter.

The error message is in formatting_ostream.hpp (boost 1.59.0 line 782)

```
template< typename StreamT, typename T >
inline typename boost::log::aux::enable_if_formatting_ostream< StreamT, StreamT& >::type
operator<< (StreamT& strm, T const& value)
{...}
```

With Visual Studio 2013 the message say's:

```
Error   818 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::exception' (or there is no acceptable conversion) d:\prg\boost\1.59.0\include\boost\log\utility\formatting_ostream.hpp
```

My intention is, i have an own exception class (defined in namespace my_space) which inherits from std::exception, so i can throw my own but catch a std::exception.

```
using namespace my_space;
try {
    // throw(std::runtime_error("something happend."));
    throw(my_exception(0x1, "something happend."));
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e << std::endl;  // works just fine
    MY_LOG_ERROR(slg) << log::add_value("Exception", e); // compile error
}
```

How to achieve this without polluting the std namespace with my own functions/overloads or creating double catch-blocks?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems in your question that I'll address separately below.

## 1. Name lookup.

In C++, unqualified function calls, such as the `operator<<` in your streaming expression, involve the [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), which basically produces a set of candidate functions that you may be calling. Out of this set the actual function is then selected according to the [overload resolution rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). For the call to complete it is essential that (a) the intended function is in the candidate set and (b) that it is not ambiguous with respect to other functions in the set, considering the way the function is called (number of provided arguments and their types, explicit template parameters, etc.) In your case (a) is not fulfilled.

Put simply and closer to your code, the `operator<<` lookup is performed in three stages. First, the compiler looks for a member `operator<<` in the right hand operand class. The operators defined in Boost.Log streams are found this way. Next, a free standing (non-member) operator is looked for in the namespaces enclosing the function call, starting from the inner namespaces and moving outwards. Names imported with `using` directives and declarations are also considered here. This lookup ends as soon as any `operator<<` is found. Note that the namespaces considered are different when you invoke the operator from your code and when the operator is invoked from Boost.Log, when you use `log::add_value`. In the first case you import `my_space` into your current namespace, so your operator is found. In the latter case Boost.Log does not import your namespace, so your operator is not found.

Lastly, the compiler performs argument-dependent lookup ([ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)) to collect additional function you might be calling. Basically, it looks for the operator in the associated namespaces which are comprised of:

- The namespace where the type of every argument in the function call is declared. That means that namespace `std` is considered in both cases because `std::exception` is declared there. When Boost.Log is used, its internal namespace where the stream type is declared is also considered (it contains a few operators but none of them accepts `std::exception`).
- If the function is a template, namespaces of its template argument types are also similarly considered.
- If the function argument types or function template argument types are templates themselves, those template arguments' namespaces are also similarly considered. This is done recursively.

The ADL finds `operator<<` in namespace `std` but none of them accepts `std::exception`. The net effect of the operator lookup here is that your operator in `my_space` is only found because of your `using`-directive, which doesn't help when the operator is called from another point of the program, such as Boost.Log code.

When implementing operators, the best practice is to rely on ADL finding those operators. This means that the operators supporting a type must be placed in the same namespace where that type is declared. In case of `std::exception`, this is namespace `std`. Technically, adding stuff to namespace `std` results in undefined behavior (as per [namespace.std]/1), so the best solution would be to define your own stream manipulator in your namespace and use it to output exceptions into streams:

```
namespace my_space {

template< typename T >
struct my_manip
{
  T const& value;
};
template< typename T >
my_manip< T > to_stream(T const& value) {
  my_manip< T > m = { value };
  return m;
}

template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT >
std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& operator<< (
  std::basic_ostream< CharT, TraitsT >& strm,
  my_manip< std::exception > const& e)
{
  // some printout stuff here
  strm << e.value.what();
  return strm;
}

} // namespace my_space

try {
  // ...
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  std::cerr << my_space::to_stream(e) << std::endl;
}
```

You can also provide a generalized `operator<<` for `my_manip`, if you like.

## 2. Adding Boost.Log attributes.

If your original intention is to attach exceptions to a log record then I'm afraid you're not doing it the right way. The `add_value` manipulator does not determine the runtime type of the value you provide, which means it saves a copy of `std::exception`, thus losing any diagnostic information that is provided by the derived class (including the `what()` message). This is known as [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

You can go multiple routes to implement what you want. First, you can format the error message in the place where you caught the exception.

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
  MY_LOG_ERROR(slg) << e.what();
}
```

You won't be able to use it as an attribute value in sinks or formatters, but this might be enough for you. You can also use your custom manipulator, of course:

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
  MY_LOG_ERROR(slg) << my_space::to_stream(e);
}
```

If you do need it as an attribute value, you will have to choose what kind of information you want. For example, if all you need is the error message, you could attach it instead of the exception:

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
  MY_LOG_ERROR(slg) << log::add_value("ErrorMessage", std::string(e.what()));
}
```

If the exception itself is what you need then you need C++11 `exception_ptr`:

```
catch (std::exception& e) {
  MY_LOG_ERROR(slg) << log::add_value("Exception", std::current_exception());
}
```

In C++03 you can use [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) or implement your custom mechanism of determining the dynamic type of the exception. Note that the standard library or Boost.Exception also don't provide `operator<<` for `exception_ptr`, so you'll have to implement custom formatters for that.