# Outputting user defined structure with boost::log

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I'm trying to output content of *boost::asio::streambuf* object with *boost::log* library. I defined *operator<<* overload in the following way:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const boost::asio::streambuf& buffer)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer.size(); ++i)
    {
        ostr << hex << (int) buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data())[i] << " ";
    }
    return ostr;
}
```

But after trying to output the content of the buffer:

```
 BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << buffer;
```

I have the following error:

> In file included from
>   /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/third_party/lib/boost/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:31:0,
>                    from /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/third_party/lib/boost/boost/log/trivial.hpp:23,
>                    from /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/server/src/server.cpp:14:
>   /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/third_party/lib/boost/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:
>   In instantiation of 'typename
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::enable_if_formatting_ostream::type boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<<(StreamT&, T&)
>   [with StreamT =
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream; T =
>   boost::asio::basic_streambuf<>; typename
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::enable_if_formatting_ostream::type =
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream&]':
>   /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/third_party/lib/boost/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:212:51:
>   required from 'typename
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::enable_if_record_ostream::type boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<<(StreamT&, T&)
>   [with StreamT = boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream; T
>   = boost::asio::basic_streambuf<>; typename boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::enable_if_record_ostream::type =
>   boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream&]'
>   /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/server/src/server.cpp:88:47:
>   required from here
>   /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/third_party/lib/boost/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:840:19:
>   error: cannot bind
>   'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream::ostream_type
>   {aka std::basic_ostream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'
>        strm.stream() << value;
>                      ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
>                    from /home/bobeff/work/asio_netcomm_poc/server/src/server.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1
>   of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
>   [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp =
>   boost::asio::basic_streambuf<>]'
>        operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
>        ^

What is the right way to output the content of the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator<<` is not found by ADL. See the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524347/boost-log-stdexception-formatter-unable-to-find-operator-overload-in-own-nam/32538936#32538936) answer.