# How to define output stream operator for boost log and a custom type

Tags: c++, templates, boost-log, stream-operators

I was able to define the output stream operator for a simple struct, however, not for std::array. The following code fails to compile. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

using hash_t = std::array< unsigned char, 32 >;

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, hash_t const& arr )
{
    os << "ole!";
    return os;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    hash_t arr;
    std::cerr << arr << std::endl; // complies cleanly
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << arr; // Error
    return 0;
}
```

Here come the errors.

GCC (boost 1.55, gcc-4.9.2):

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:23,
                 from trival.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT>& boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::operator<<(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT>&, const T&) [with CharT = char; TraitsT = std::char_traits<char>; AllocatorT = std::allocator<char>; T = std::array<unsigned char, 32ul>]’:
trival.cpp:18:30:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:710:19: error: cannot bind ‘boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char>::ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
     strm.stream() << value;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from trival.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::array<unsigned char, 32ul>]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

Clang error (boost 1.64, clang-800.0.42.1):

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:23:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:36:
/usr/local/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:878:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream_type' (aka
      'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >') and 'std::__1::array<unsigned char, 32>')
    strm.stream() << value;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:390:51: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<<<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
      std::__1::array<unsigned char, 32> >' requested here
    static_cast< formatting_ostream_type& >(strm) << value;
                                                  ^
/Users/adam/GitPen/BoostLog/trival/trival.cpp:18:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<<<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream<char>, std::__1::array<unsigned char, 32> >' requested here
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << arr;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not like this answer.

To get this to work properly at the moment you need to add your `operator<<` to `namespace std`:

```
namespace std{
   std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const hash_t& arr )
   {/*...*/}
}
```

because of how ADL works, it is going to only consider the `operator<<` and its specializations within `namespace std`

You wont like it because adding this function to `namespace std` is not a legal thing to do:

[namespace.std]

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a
>   namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
>   for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>   and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

Maybe the easiest thing to do would be to inherit from (and do nothing else) the `std` type instead:

```
struct hash_t : std::array< unsigned char, 32 >{};
```

Comment: Ah, it's ADL! I think inheriting does the trick. Rather than saying `using hash_t = std::array< char, 2 >;` I just do `struct hash_t : std::array< char, 2 > {};`.

Comment: @AndrewDwojc: Exactly

Comment: This answer is relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524347/boost-log-stdexception-formatter-unable-to-find-operator-overload-in-own-nam/32538936#32538936 The manipulator approach may be preferable when inheriting is undesirable (e.g. you don't want `hash_t` to be a new type), too tedious (e.g. you have to forward many constructors to the base class) or not possible (e.g. the type is `final`).

Comment: Yes. I up-voted your answer and went for the `struct hash_t : std::array< char, 32 > {};` trick. However, I realized I will hit the same issue again once I define `<<` for other std types (e.g. `vector< T >`). Good to know it's just ADL when you see those long compiler messages.